# Enable ACL permissions on shared folder in Synology DSM 5.2

Tags: permissions, acl, synology

My Syno DS213+ is running on DSM 5.2-5644

I have several shared folders that don't have the option to edit ACL permissions, because they were created before DSM 5.0

In the [release notes of DSM 5.0](https://www.synology.com/en-global/releaseNote/DS213+), under "What's New in DSM 5.0", topic 5, it says:

> For shared folders created in DSM 4.3 or earlier, you can either
>   convert the existing permissions to Windows ACL, or leave the
>   permission unchanged.

And also, in the syno knowledge base, i found [this article](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/tutorials/453#t2) on how to enable these ACL permissions.
In topic "To enable ACL for a DiskStation shared folder", point 3 says:

> Click Edit, click the Windows Access Control List tab, select Allow
>   editing Windows Access Control List, and then click OK.

However, the *Windows Access Control List tab* is not available in DSM 5.2

Does anybody know how to enable the ACL permissions on a shared folder in DSM 5.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. Found the answer.
Control Panel > Shared Folder > Action > Convert to Windows ACL